# How to select data from Excel using a new interval

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have a set of data in an Excel sheet that look something like that

```
Distance
1.0
1.3
1.4
1.5
1.8
2.0
2.5
```

I would like to select this set of data based on a new interval of 0.5 which will look like this:

```
Distance    
1.0
1.5
2.0
2.5
```

This new arranged data will be placed in a new Excel sheet. Is there any way to do this in an Office Excel 2003 environment?

Comment: Yes, there is. Probably easiest with VBA, but complex formulas could probably be developed also.  Let us know what you come up with, and we'll try to help you over the rough spots.

Comment: Your example fails to adequately show all of the conditions that may occur. What if the data was *1.5, 1.9, 2.1, 2.5* ? What are the expected results?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
Sub getCorrectIntervals()
Dim rng As Range
Dim r As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim interval As Double
interval = 0.5

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set rng = ws.Range("A2:A8") 'can be change to whatever, and can even be made dynamic


For Each r In rng
    If Evaluate("Mod(" & r.Value & "," & interval & ")") = 0 Then
        MsgBox r.Address & " is divisible by " & interval
        'Code here to put r.value into new sheet...?
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: had to include 'Evaluate' since the mod function will only accept integers, and the interval we were using is 0.5. Looks a little crazy, but really simple.